# How to wait for animation -- completion block

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I'm working on an app where two views meet somewhere on the screen. When they meet, a collision detector fires off this method. It's supposed to identify the appropriate base and then send both views to it. It does exactly that, but it happens instantly instead of over a period of 4 seconds. What am I missing? RADIUS is defined above this code. Does it have anything to do with arrow not being a UIView? The spriteView class is a subclass of UIView.

```
-(void)sendToBase:(spriteView *)arrow
{
   int teamNumber = arrow.teamNumber;
   // Find the location of the base.
   for (UIView *scaledView in self.view.subviews) {
      if (scaledView.tag == 100) {
         for (UIView *base in scaledView.subviews) {
            if (base.tag >= 1000) {
               if (teamNumber + 1000 == base.tag) {
                  // We found the right base.
                  CGPoint newCenter;
                  newCenter.x = base.center.x + arc4random() % (int) floor(RADIUS) - RADIUS/2.0;
                  newCenter.y = base.center.y + arc4random() % (int) floor(RADIUS) - RADIUS/2.0;
                  [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
                     [arrow setCenter:newCenter];
                  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // After walking back to base, remove and create new objects
                     [arrow removeFromSuperview];
                     [self addArrow:scaledView toTeam:teamNumber];
                  }];
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

On the off-chance that the class type mismatch was the problem, I modified the code thusly, with the same results.

```
-(void)sendToBase:(spriteView *)arrow
{
   UIView *uiSpriteView = (UIView *)arrow;
   int teamNumber = arrow.teamNumber;
   // Find the location of the base.
   for (UIView *scaledView in self.view.subviews) {
      if (scaledView.tag == 100) {
         for (UIView *base in scaledView.subviews) {
            if (base.tag >= 1000) {
               if (teamNumber + 1000 == base.tag) {
                  // We found the right base.
                  CGPoint newCenter;
                  newCenter.x = base.center.x + arc4random() % (int) floor(RADIUS) - RADIUS/2.0;
                  newCenter.y = base.center.y + arc4random() % (int) floor(RADIUS) - RADIUS/2.0;
                  [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
                     [uiSpriteView setCenter:newCenter];
                  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // After walking back to base, remove and create new objects
                     [arrow removeFromSuperview];
                     [self addArrow:scaledView toTeam:teamNumber];
                  }];
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the only requirement is that arrow be a subclass of UIView, and that setCenter be implemented by UIView and not the subclass.

Comment: Well, arrow is a subclass of UIView, and setCenter is not messed with in the subclass, which I gather is what you are saying. UIView, not spriteView has to handle the setting of the center. The movement happens. It just happens instantly.

Comment: What happens if you add `NSLog("Finished: %@",finished?@"Yes":@"No");` to your completion block?  I am guess it will say, "No".

Comment: @AdamLockhart -- Yep, and it would be good to note how much delay there is before you get to the completion block.

Comment: I'll try that when I get back to Xcode. setCenter is animatable, right?

Comment: setCenter is listed as animatable, and you could always use transform to do the same thing (more clumsily) if you wanted.

Comment: (Although I find the documentation of `center` pretty confusing.)

Comment: Interesting. When a collision happens, there are two spriteView objects involved in the collision. The result of the NSLog (@Adam, you were missing an @ sign) was 2012-12-03 16:35:40.332 DareBase[7505:907] 99.753723
2012-12-03 16:35:40.383 DareBase[7505:907] Finished: No
2012-12-03 16:35:40.405 DareBase[7505:907] Finished: Yes (the first timestamp is the time of the collision detection)

Comment: `center` is listed as animatable, but unlike other animatable properties like alpha, is says to use the `beginAnimations:context: method to animate it.

Comment: If you can post a MWE that would help to reproduce your situation

Comment: I have another idea. It looks like the code that does the collision detection occurs in the animation block (of the animation that results in a collision). That is what is kicking off the above code. I think I should move that code to the completion block instead so it is run in the run thread, which I think is required for it to work.

Comment: @Gabro, I'm a newbie here. Can you explain what a MWE is?

Comment: MWE: Minimal Working Example

Comment: As @picciano was saying a MWE is a Minimal Working Example.
If you provide a piece of code that is complete enough to test it and reproduce the problem, it's much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem (using setCenter). There are two animations going on.

The first animation occurs before the collision.
The second animation occurs as a result of the collision.

The code that detects the collision (and thus spawns the second animation) was in the animation block instead of the completion block. When I moved the code to the completion block, the second animation worked. Well, almost. One of the two arrows were animated properly. I can probably ferret out the other issue now that one of them is working.

Comment: That's great. Please follow-up with a comment once everything is working. I'm really curious to see if this resolves all of the issues. Thanks!

Comment: The completion block is still a block, right? Meaning it's running in its own thread. Maybe that's why only one of the two animations is working. One animation per animation thread? So I probably should just set a flag in the completion block and kick off both animations from the run thread after the completion block completes. I'll try that next.

Comment: @picciano, I solved the other half of the problem. The first animation, the one that creates the collision, is driven by a repeating timer. There was a bug in the code to skip over arrows involved in a collision. The result was that two animations were trying to happen at the same time on the same object. The main animation now correctly skips over the ones heading back to base. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you have to use the `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimations` methods to animate the `center` property.

Comment: The pubs make the same statement about transform, but it animates with animationWithDuration just fine.  I think the pub just hasn't caught up with the changes.  (But it's easy to scaffold in the use of beginAnimations to be sure.)

Comment: I'd say try it. It sounds like this has resolved the issue for others.  Other parts of the API docs for this class have been updated, I suspect that there is something unique about this one that sometimes requires the old-style animation.

Comment: That's how I move the arrows around in the rest of the code, but I wasn't using a rotation transform in this case, and I saw another post here about someone using setCenter, so I thought I'd try it.